# Verb agreement: We [company name]

Tags: grammar

I have seen a company description as follows:
We [company name] is a specialized manufacturer of…
Is the verb agreement correct here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an appallingly ungrammatical construction, caused by someone trying to slavishly follow the principle that [in American English, collective nouns almost always trigger singular verb agreement](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/1339/2637). That issue doesn't arise in "British English", since we quite naturally use singular *or* plural for things like *company, family, group*, according to context.

But I don't think any competent speaker (not even an American) would actually produce OP's example. So presumably the company (or at least, the *speaker*) is not a native speaker of English.

Comment: Collective nouns are the one thing that have always boggled my mind. Though AmE/BrE use them differently in speech, we still get taught the "proper" way in school (or at least we did when I was in school). And I just could not get it. To this day the "correct"/BrE way of using collective nouns confuses the life out of me...

Comment: The rule I was taught was something like "if you're talking about everyone it's one way, but if you mean each individual person it's another..." And then I could never figure out how you could tell if a "team" was referring to individuals or the whole... Anyway, +1. I agree. I just don't grok the collective nouns! Maybe I should go back and try to re-learn them as an adult, but I've never bothered. (Also what's with the air quotes around British English? ;))

Comment: @Wendikidd: It seems to me the key point is implicit in your comments. I don't think Brits are normally "taught" anything about such usage, *because there is no formal "rule"*. To me, the US "formally correct" system is obsessively rigid, and *in extremis* leads to ridiculous situations like OP's. The "air quotes" are because in this specific context I think **BrE** simply means **the way people speak naturally when unfettered by inappropriate rules**. Check out [The FBI know/s we're here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The+FBI+know+we%27re+here%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)...

Comment: ...and in both cases you'll see contexts where the FBI are referenced using ***they*** immediately afterwards. You can try to talk your way out of that by pointing to "singular 'they'", but I really don't buy it. When they're after you, the FBI are usually plural *in the mind of the person being pursued*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, your answer would be correct if the question had anything to do with the collective nouns. There is an appositive/apposition there. http://www.write.com/writing-resources-articles/general-writing/grammar/appositives/.
BTW: you are right neither the speaker nor the company is a native speaker of English. Actually they are Chinese.

Comment: @Lucian: You can call it an example of apposition if you want, but I don't see what difference that makes. The net result is it's a grammatical error which can *only* arise because the writer is slavishly applying the AmE "group is singular" convention to [the company], which is incompatible with conjoined plural "we".

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I agree with your supplementary words of enlightenment. +1 for the appallingly ungrammatical construction caused by someone trying to slavishly apply that principle.
I truly don’t know if in English it’s always incompatible to conjoin plural with singular, but consider your words correct.
In my language can say: “We, the king of…”, or: “We, [the company name],…”

Comment: @Lucian: The ***royal "we"*** is no longer used in English, even by the Queen. So ["We, the king of France..."](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22we+the+king+of+france+born%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example, is no longer either current or "grammatical". Forms like *"I/We the undersigned [do solemnly declare blah blah]"* are fine because *"the undersigned"* can be singular or plural as fits the context, but unless there's some "excuse" like that, you can't mix pluralities with conjoined/equated "apposition" constructions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thank you very much! Now everything is clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think the author is trying to add the pronoun *we* just to emphasize that they are the company. So, there, it seems a superfluous word.

> We-- *(m dash here)* XYZ Company **is** a specialized manufacturer of...

The verb *are* could have gone in that place as in this case...

> We, XYZ Company, **are** a specialized manufacturer of...

Not the part of this answer but related to the question -

> The use of plural verb after a singular noun is **possible** when you denote it as a group of persons. On the other hand, it'd take a singular noun if you consider that as one entity.

Compare -

> The crowd **was** cheering seeing Sachin's batting - all people were cheering. 
>  The crowd **were** clapping and shouting - some of them were clapping and others were shouting.

This can happen in case of the word *company* as well. Company *is* and Company *are* is possible.

Further reading [here](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp).

Comment: I am of the opinion that the "collective noun->plural verb" construction is mostly a BrE/AmE distinction, not a "part of group/all of group" distinction.  I would cheerfully say "the crowd was clapping and shouting" if parts of the crowd were only clapping and other parts were only shouting; using "were" there sounds wrong to me.

Comment: @Hellion Isn't it surprising that every answer of mine would have a comment of AmE or BrE! Is this forum localized? As a non-native speaker do I need to confirm with the native speakers everything that I learn from books. This said, all the books on English written by non-native authors should be barred from selling. Isn't it? Don't comment now that **we don't say** International English is incorrect/bad; had this been the case, you wouldn't have written **wrong to me**. cont...

Comment: Also, why don't we have **English - The Way Native Takes It** as an all separate forum and let this be **International English**, a neutral forum without any favoritism. In addition, I'm **native speaker** of Hindi but all what I know in **Hindi** is not perfect in grammar. Things are **not** incorrect as they simply **sound off** to the native speakers. At times, natives too have to **learn** something that **actually exists** but never been heard by them.

Comment: @Maulik V, it’s amazing how instinctively you identified the correct spelling, comas, dashes, parenthesis, but couldn’t identify the appositive/apposition. http://www.write.com/writing-resources-articles/general-writing/grammar/appositives/. 
It’s a simple subject verb agreement, where the subject is the pronoun “we”. The appositive only explains, identifies, qualifies, renames etc. the subject.

Comment: I don't believe any significant number of native speakers would make this singular/plural distinction for a *crowd, family*, etc.

Comment: "The use of plural verb after a singular noun is possible" -- This is misleading.