# Its or Their to refer to a company?

Tags: pronouns, grammatical-number

> The company will issue **(their, its)** annual report next month.

In this case, should I use "its" or "their"?

Comment: Related: [Verb agreement: We \[company name\]](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/19399/3281), [Are collective nouns always plural, or are certain ones singular? - English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1338/11482). Without having any specific context, treating a company as a singular noun and using a singular verb and the pronoun *it* would be a safer choice in general.

Comment: The only right answer is that you can use either one, because both are used by native speakers everywhere.

Comment: "The company will issue *an* annual report" avoids the problem completely :)

Comment: Is this American English, British English, or another dialect?

Answer (score 8):

Both *its* and *their* are pronouns. While *its* is a singular pronoun, *their* is a plural pronoun.

A *company* is a collective noun. In AmE, *Company* takes a singular verb form and singular pronoun. While in BrE, *Company* takes a plural verb form and plural pronoun.

So, depending on that, both are correct.

In AmE:

> The company will issue its annual report next month.

In BrE:

> The company will issue their annual report next month.

Comment: In BE, you can use either the plural  noun or singular pronoun for a company.

Comment: @Khan In AE, you can use either the plural noun or singular pronoun for a company.

Comment: 'their' is increasingly used as a singular pronoun too.

Comment: I just checked today's issue of the British "Financial Times" newspaper, and it consistently refers to companies as "it," not "they". The (rather old-fashioned) BrEng meaning of "a company" = "a group of people" is a *plural* collective noun, or course. A "company" in the sense of a "commercial organization" is a type of "legal entity," (i.e., without getting too deep in legal definitions, "something which is not a person, but which which has the same legal rights and obligations that an individual person can have") and as such it is logically singular, not plural.

Answer (score 6):

Your question: should I use *its* or *their* in: *The company will issue their/its annual report next month*?

In this instance, I'd recommend using ***its***:

> *The company will issue **its** annual report next month.*

---

This, among other things, echoes Kelly's answer and [Fantasier's answer to an old question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/24919/3281): "If a collective noun is seen as a whole, sole, impersonal unit, then singular verbs are more common. If it is seen as a collection of people doing personal things, then plural verbs are more common. In American English the verb for the noun is usually singular in all cases except *family* (if you don't quantify it with *members of, people in* etc)."

Which also echoes [an old answer by FumbleFingers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/19448/3281): "(in "British English") [W]e quite naturally use singular or plural for things like *company, family, group*, according to context", and information relating to collective nouns which is relatively to find around the web, including on [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular).

---

Back to your sentence, it's clear that it's safer to use *its* in either British or American English. Even though it *may* be possible to use *their* in British English (and also in American English), I'd personally use *it* in that specific instance; and though I can't say exactly why, this [Google Ngram chart](https://goo.gl/COZ2QK) appears to support my choice:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, Google Books Ngram Viewer would suggest that *company* is more often treated as singular.

[image]

But all you can really draw from this is that it's acceptable to treat *company* as either singular or plural.

I think it comes down to whether or not you want to emphasise the single legal entity or the group of people who make up the company.

In the case of an annual report, it is issued by the single legal entity and so I would use the singular:

> The company will issue its annual report next month.

Answer (score 2):

In AmE, I think it is 'it'. So,

> The company will issue *its* annual report next month *(AmE)*

In BrE, companies are often called with a plural pronoun

> The company will issue their annual report next month *(BrE)*.

---

My opinion

If you are talking about the 'company' use 'it'. If you are peculiar about mentioning the owners or authorities, mention 'their'.

Comment: Not really. In American English, it is perfectly normal to use *their* to refer to a company.

Answer (score 1):

> The company will issue (their, its) annual report next month.

A company in this grammar is classed as a single entity, so will release *its* (as ownership) annual report.

A Board of Members would release *their* (joint ownership) annual report.