# Produce or Produces. Why should I choose one of these options and, what is the grammatical rule for its use in this expression?

Tags: verbs

Our company ________a wide range of products for industrial machines. It started operations in 1978 and was originally a family company. It has been a marked leader for several years. We are based in Japan and have a subsidiary in Malasya. At presente, we are setting up a new distribution center in England. Next quarter, we are going to start a sales campaign in Europe. A)Produces B)Produce

P.S. Could you please explain to me with gramatical references? Thanks.

Comment: This [previous question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/71085/its-or-their-to-refer-to-a-company/71091) suggests that "company" is a singular entity, but there may be a better duplicate question. It may depend on BrE or AmE.

Comment: Ask yourself how to make a basic sentence in English in the third person singular with an active verb. "This questions seek***s*** to answer a question about the verb produce." There is no "expression" involved here.

Comment: Lambie and Weather Vane. I would like you to understand what I understood from your response. Is that what you wanted to tell me?

- Why not the "b"?
Because "company" is in the 3rd person singular (pronoun "It"), therefore, the conjugation of the verb "to produce" is given the suffix "-s".
- Why the alternative "a"?
For, as explained in the previous question, the statement speaks of a current subject, still active at the moment of speech.

Answer (score 1):

Why not the "b"? Because "company" is in the 3rd person singular (pronoun "It"), therefore, the conjugation of the verb "to produce" is given the suffix "-s".

- Why the alternative "a"? For, as explained in the previous question, the statement speaks of a current subject, still active at the moment of speech.